# How to draw straight eyebrows in turtle python?

Tags: python, graphics, python-turtle

How to draw straight eyebrows in turtle python?
like this one: [Eyebrow types image](https://www.istockphoto.com/vector/eyebrow-shapes-with-eyes-various-types-of-eyebrows-trimming-vector-illustration-gm1213516204-352709680)

The Code I am Using:

```
import turtle
eyeborw1=turtle.Turtle()
eyeborw1.pensize(5)
eyeborw1.pencolor('black')
eyeborw1.width(10)
eyeborw1.circle(20,10)
eyeborw1.forward(85)
eyeborw1.circle(0,0,-16) 
turtle.done()
```

The code did not give me the output I wanted. What should I do now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you are frustrated because you don't understand why things are happening the way they are. Turtle assignments are typically given to beginners as a way to introduce them to reading documentation and enable them to see how their code and code sequence affects the outcome (in a simple visual format). You should try and play around with this more, the documentation for turtle is a great resource and may be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html).

*Some things to note about your code, however.*

In your attempt, you're using both `eyeborw1.pensize(5)` and `eyeborw1.width(10)`. Width is just an alias for pensize, so your previous pensize line has no use.

Not sure what `eyeborw1.circle(0,0,-16)` is trying to achieve. There is no effect from this command, as radius is 0. The `steps` parameter is only useful when a circle is actually drawn.

I think you're on the right track with using `circle` and `forward`. Once you feel that you've created the general eyebrow shape you want, you can try to make your pensize change throughout the eyebrow to it gradually thin by the end tip.